# why does my method don't work for deleting firebase object? on vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

**what I try to do:**

so far I can't get the method remove from firebase, I read the docs but I don't know why it won't happen... the snapshot for retrieving the data works just fine, but not the delete method I try... it was giving me an error on the reference until I tried the _key on the onClick button.

no, it drops some data to the console but it won't delete the gigs/user/key object any ideas why?

```
<template>
  <v-container id="tutorials">
      <h1>Gigs Available!</h1>
           <!-- loop over the tutorials -->
           <div  class="Agrid d-grid">
           <div
           class="Amodule  back"
           v-for="gig in allGigs"
           :key="gig._key">
           <div class="fill-height">
             <v-container >
              <a @click.prevent="deleteGigs(gig._key)" class="card-link">
                 <v-icon color=red>mdi-delete</v-icon>
               </a>
             <br>
             <div class="d-flex align-start">
               <h3 class="j-title center mb-00">{{ gig.gigtitle}}</h3>
             </div>
             <h6 class="">{{gig.companyname}}</h6>
             <v-row class="d-flex ">
               <p class="col-tres mdi mdi-clock text--secondary"> {{ gig.vacanttype }} </p>
               <p class="col-tres mdi mdi-earth text--secondary"> {{ gig.giglocation }} </p>
               <p class="col-tres mdi mdi-calendar text--secondary">{{gig.gigdate}} </p>
             </v-row>
             <v-divider class="mx-4"></v-divider>
             <h5 class="left text-body-2">Company description</h5><br>
             <p class="content"> {{ gig.companydescription}}</p><br>
             <h5 class="left text-body-2">Gig description</h5><br>
             <p class="content"> {{ gig.gigdescription}}</p><br>
             <h5 class="left text-body-2">Gig benefits</h5><br>
             <p class="content"> {{ gig.gigbenefits}}</p><br>
             <h5 class="left text-body-2">Skills</h5><br>
             <p class="content"> {{ gig.gigskills}}</p><br>
           </v-container>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
     <br>

  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
import firebase from '@/plugins/firebase'
let db = firebase.database();
//let usersRef = db.ref('users');
let gigRef = db.ref('gigs');

export default {
  name: 'EditGigs',
  data: () => ({
  authUser: null,
  allGigs: [], // initialise an array
}),
  methods: {
    deleteGigs(gig) {
    gigRef.child(gig).remove()
    console.log(gigRef.child(gig))
}
  },
  created: function() {
    //data => console.log(data.user, data.credential.accessToken)
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          gigRef.once('value', snapshot => {
            const val = snapshot.val()
            if (val) {
              this.allGigs = Object.values(val).flatMap(gigs =>
              Object.entries(gigs).map(([ _key, gig ]) => ({ _key, ...gig})))
            }
            console.log(snapshot.val())
          });
        }
     })
}
}
```

**after clicking the delete button i get this :**

```
Reference {repo: Repo, path: Path, queryParams_: QueryParams, orderByCalled_: false}
orderByCalled_: false
path: Path {pieces_: Array(2), pieceNum_: 0}
queryParams_: QueryParams {limitSet_: false, startSet_: false, startNameSet_: false, endSet_: false, endNameSet_: false, …}
repo: Repo {repoInfo_: RepoInfo, app: FirebaseAppImpl, dataUpdateCount: 1, statsListener_: null, eventQueue_: EventQueue, …}
database: Database
key: "-MjxHR5FjvNgB_cvp5Q3"
parent: Reference
orderByCalled_: false
path: Path {pieces_: Array(1), pieceNum_: 0}
queryParams_: QueryParams {limitSet_: false, startSet_: false, startNameSet_: false, endSet_: false, endNameSet_: false, …}
repo: Repo {repoInfo_: RepoInfo, app: FirebaseAppImpl, dataUpdateCount: 1, statsListener_: null, eventQueue_: EventQueue, …}
database: Database
key: "gigs"
parent: Reference
ref: Reference
```

[UI thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hoqM.png)

if I do this removes all my ref object thing...

```
  methods: {
  deleteGigs(gig) {
    gigRef.remove()
    //console.log(gigRef.child(gig))
    console.log(gig)
   }
  },
```

Comment: You are indeed logging the `Reference`. Can you `console.log(gig)` in delete method and share the output ? Also make the method async and add an `await` before remove statment

Comment: I get : -MjxUCHolM-AW9pHL_gz  as the output using console.log(gig) in the method

Comment: I tried it but not sure if I am doing it right, the Firebase object seems to still be on the DB 

  `methods: {
  async deleteGigs(gig) {
  await  gigRef.child(gig).remove()
    //console.log(gigRef.child(gig))
    console.log(gig)
   }`  how do i do the async await in the method for this ?

Comment: i tried :   `methods: {
  async deleteGigs(gig) {
  return gigRef.child(gig).remove()
  .then (console.log('what is going on?'))
  .catch (err => {
    //console.log(gigRef.child(gig))
    console.error('fetch failed', err);
  })
 }
  },`  got `what is going on?`

Comment: if i do this :   `deleteGigs(gig) {
    gigRef.remove()
    //console.log(gigRef.child(gig))
    console.log(gig)
   } `    it removed my whole ref X'D lol

Comment: @renaudtarnec trying is not working i need a real solution, i think firebase is buggy i am just being honest

Comment: I rolled back your last edit.  Please don't edit your question to include the answer; that just makes things confusing for future users.  You can post an actual answer on your own question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer:

Firebase snapshot key was design this way: [firebase key website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key)

Accessing the key on any DataSnapshot will return the key for the location that generated it. However, accessing the key on the root URL of a Database will return null.

So it's it obligates us to relate it to a key inside the object which makes the firebase real-time DB **really insecure**

here is another picture to describe the bad design problem:

[real time design of key herarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKzes.png)

that anyone know if mongo DB has this issue?